# Trying to make overlaid span and h2 over images but being unsuccessful

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a span like a banner and some center aligned h2 over an image gallery but not doing to  great at it.

This is for a crash course class and the assignment is due on Wednesday night, I am going to keep debugging the code tonight and tomorrow but I figured that I would use the resources available to me and ask the community.

Any and all help is appreciated. I don't even need the "correct answer", I just need some guidance to what I should do.

How do I fix my mistakes?

```
<div class="sizing">
<div class="maincontent">
    <section>
        <ul>

            <li class="gallery"> 
                <img src="assets/images/holding-and-point-on-tablet-pc-P4YGEVW.jpg" alt="Hangman">
                <span><h2>Hangman</h2></span>
            </li>
            <li> 
                <img src="assets/images/game-PJVG95Z.jpg" alt="RPG Game">
                <span><h2>Hangman</h2></span>
            </li>
            <li> 
                <img src="assets/images/concentrated-man-sitting-at-home-indoors-play-PZGRWH7.jpg" alt="Trivia Game ">
                <span><h2>Hangman</h2></span>
            </li>
            <li> 
                <img src="assets/images/statistics-strategy-analysis-diagram-information-P9KEFGF.jpg" alt="Reutgers">
                <span><h2>Hangman</h2></span>
            </li>
            <li>
                 <img src= "assets/images/note-tied-to-rock-PUJU6N2.jpg" alt="Rock Paper Scissors">
                 <span><h2>Hangman</h2></span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </section>
</div>
</div>

.sizing {
max-width: 960px;

margin: 0 auto;
}

.maincontent {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    float: left;
    max-width:650px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    padding-bottom:30px;
}

img {
height:"";
width:40%;
float: left;
display: inline-block;
position:relative;
margin-right:2px;
margin: 0 auto;
margin:30px;
border:1px solid #ddd;
}


.gallery {
position:relative;
 }
.gallery span {
position:absolute;
bottom:20px;
left:0px;
background: #4aaaac;
}
```

[The example I am trying to mimic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j3sfq.png)

Comment: For one, you could make images as `background-image` instead of using `<img>`

Comment: I'm just curious, does it really need to be inside `<ul>` or it is just your preference?

Comment: it doesnt have to be in ul, I just was starting there with it

Answer (score 0):

apply div around `img` and `span` tag like this, it will help to apply absolute positioning and overlap your h2 tag

```
    [![<style>

.sizing {
max-width: 960px;

margin: 0 auto;
}

.maincontent {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    float: left;
    max-width:650px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    padding-bottom:30px;
}

img {
height:"";
width:40%;
float: left;
display: inline-block;
position:relative;
margin-right:2px;
margin: 0 auto;
margin:30px;
border:1px solid #ddd;
}


.gallery {
position:relative;
 }
.gallery span {
position:absolute;
bottom:20px;
left:0px;
background: #4aaaac;
}
.sp{
position:absolute;
top:24%;
left:14%
}
</style>

<div class="sizing">
<div class="maincontent">
    <section>
        <ul>

            <li class="gallery"> 
               <div>
                <span><h2>Hangman1</h2></span>
                </div>
            </li>

            <li>
                 <div   style="width:200px;height:200px;background-color:green;">
                 <span class="sp"><h2>Hangman2</h2></span>
                 </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </section>
</div>
</div>][1]][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this pretty easily by cleaning up the code and setting your image as a `background-image`, rather than using a separate `img` element.

Edit: Here's the same principle in a version that uses an unordered list, in case you need that. The images are placeholders and the width/height of each gallery item can be easily adjusted:

```css
.sizing {
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.maincontent {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}

.gallery {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 20px;
}

#gallery-first {
  background: url('http://via.placeholder.com/200x150') no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

#gallery-second {
  background: url('http://via.placeholder.com/200x150') no-repeat;
}

#gallery-third {
  background: url('http://via.placeholder.com/200x150') no-repeat;
}

#gallery-fourth {
  background: url('http://via.placeholder.com/200x150') no-repeat;
}

#gallery-fifth {
  background: url('http://via.placeholder.com/200x150') no-repeat;
}

.gallery span {
  position: absolute;
  background: #4aaaac;
  top: 65px;
  left: 0;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="sizing">
  <div class="maincontent">
    <section>
      <ul>
        <li class="gallery" id="gallery-first">
          <span><h2>Hangman</h2></span>
        </li>
        <li class="gallery" id="gallery-second">
          <span><h2>Hangman</h2></span>
        </li>
        <li class="gallery" id="gallery-third">
          <span><h2>Hangman</h2></span>
        </li>
        <li class="gallery" id="gallery-fourth">
          <span><h2>Hangman</h2></span>
        </li>
        <li class="gallery" id="gallery-fifth">
          <span><h2>Hangman</h2></span>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: @Griffin Beste I edited my answer to demonstrate using a background image rather than an img element inside of a ul, since you're using one in your code. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Here's one

```css
.outer-div {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-image: url('http://via.placeholder.com/200x200');
}

.inner-div {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5%;
  height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #4aaaac;
}

.inner-div>span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left:50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-div">
  <div class="inner-div">
    <span>Hangman</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to Change in your HTML and no need to put the image in background. Just Try this one. You have to update only css, your HTML is Ok. And you can change li width according to your need.

```
    .sizing {
    max-width: 960px;

    margin: 0 auto;
    }

    .maincontent {
        background-color: #FFFFFF;
        float: left;
        max-width:650px;
        margin-top: 50px;
        margin-bottom: 50px;
        padding-bottom:30px;
    }
    .maincontent ul {
        list-style: none;
    }
    .maincontent ul li {
        float: left;
        margin: 5px;
        width: 185px;
        position: relative;
    }
    .maincontent ul li img { 
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;

    }
    .maincontent ul li span {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:20px;
    left:0px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    background: #4aaaac;
    }
```